# Filtros combinados en tablas relacionadas (Laravel, Livewire)

Tags: laravel, livewire

Tengo unos filtros que no están funcionando del todo bien, empecemos por las tablas, tengo una users y otra groups (que serían grupos familiares), la tabla users tiene un group_id apunta al grupo familiar de ese usuario. Todos los integrantes de cada familia están en la tabla users y dentro de un grupo familiar se diferencian por el número de adherente (0,1,2,3...).

Tabla Users
name
nroDoc (Documento de la persona)
nro_adherente
group_id

Tabla Groups
nroSocio (con este número se filtra a una familia)
direccion
telefono
...

Tengo una vista index con la tabla de datos de users y he agregado filtros que funcionan combinados, se puede buscar por nombre, documento y también por campos que tengo en la tabla groups que son nroSocio y direccion.

Por ejemplo escribo un número de socio (que indica a la familia) y quiero que me filtre a las personas que pertenecen a esa familia. Tengo un componente Livewire para esto, les comparto ahora algo de la vista:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.debounce="filters.search" id="filter-search" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="nroSocio">Nro. Socio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.debounce="filters.nroSocio" id="filter-nroSocio" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <label for="nroDoc">Documento</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.debounce="filters.nroDoc" id="filter-nroDoc" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <label for="direccion">Domicilio</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.debounce="filters.direccion" id="filter-direccion" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Los filtros declarados:

```
public $filters = [
    'search' => '',
    'nroSocio' => '',
    'nroDoc' => '',
    'direccion' => '',
];
```

Y el query:

```
$query = User::query()
  ->when($this->filters['search'], fn($query, $search) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%'))
  ->when($this->filters['nroDoc'], fn($query, $nroDoc) => $query->where('nroDoc', 'like', '%'.$nroDoc.'%'))
  ->when($this->filters['nroSocio'], fn($query, $nroSocio) => $query->orderByDesc(Group::select('nroSocio')
      ->whereColumn('group_id', 'groups.id')->where('nroSocio', 'like', '%'.$nroSocio.'%')))
  ->when($this->filters['direccion'], fn($query, $direccion) => $query->orderByDesc(Group::select('direccion')
      ->whereColumn('group_id', 'groups.id')->where('direccion', 'like', '%'.$direccion.'%')));
```

Esto funciona perfecto con los filtros name y nroDoc, filtra y muestra sólo los resultados de acuerdo al parámetro ingresado.

Aquí viene el problema, cuando filtro por nroSocio o dirección (que son campos de la tabla groups) me ubica al inicio a los usuarios que cumplen con el parámetro ingresado, o sea los encuentra bien, pero me agrega debajo el resto de los usuarios aunque no cumplan con el parámetro. No sé si tendrá que ver con el select que estoy utilizando, les agradezco si me pueden dar una mano.

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien que hace esa subconsulta para los casos que dices no funcionan, pero creería que es una caso para usar [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: Si, no conocía esa función, pareciera que es la indicada, ahora tengo que ver como escribirlo correctamente en el query que tengo armado, gracias!